# I want an exception, if django template tag `static` renders a broken URL

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to see an exception, if settings.DEBUG is true and line like this gets processed by the template engine:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
        href="{% static "foo/css/file-name-with-typo.css" %}">
```

Docs for the `static` template tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static

Background: An exception would trigger our Continous Integration system to fail and the broken could would not go live. I don't want to run code in production which produces broken links.

Comment: Solve the problem with the right tools and avoid do complex modification to django contrib package just to solve QA problems. Have you looked at this ? https://ntotten.com/2015/08/04/using-jenkins-to-detect-broken-links-on-your-site/

Comment: @MauroRocco the link you provide uses LinkChecker. Yes, this would work. But I guess this would produce much more load than necessary. Since we create all links in our django application with `reverse()` checking them would make no sense.

Comment: Sorry, but of which kind of loading you are worrying? You deploy your app on a test server and Jenkins will scan it and it's over. Reverse or not reverse it will just navigate the app as a browser.

Comment: @MauroRocco There *is* a place for what you suggest, but something that would raise an error when a developer is using `runserver` or when running `manage.py test` would be immensely useful to trap duh-type mistakes. What you are suggesting is useful to trap mistakes in the deployment procedure (e.g. files copied to the wrong location, misconfigured server).

Comment: @MauroRocco what kind of "load" I worry about? CPU and IO load. Our tests already take too much time. Running LinkChecker would running all tests last longer. I want to avoid this.

Comment: If you really want to go that way  I would suggest make your template tag that extends contrib static one. If debug check the file. Looking at the source code here should help you out : https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/staticfiles/templatetags/staticfiles.py

Comment: @MauroRocco I'd suggest not modifying the template tag, but instead subclassing the storage backend so that it checks for the presence of the relevant file in (probably) the `.url()` method. (Just call `.exists()`, then defer to super or raise an exception as needed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `url()` method to raise an error if the file doesn't exist:

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage


class CustomFileSystemStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def url(self, name):
        if not self.exists(name):
            raise ValueError('"%s" does not exist.' % name)
        return super(CustomFileSystemStorage, self).url(name)
```

In your settings.py:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'mymodule.CustomFileSystemStorage'
```